# (React) Changing True/False Value Based On Checkbox Value - Getting "TypeError: checked.map is not a function"

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to change the 'checked' value to "true" or "false" based on user checkbox selection. I have the below code and I am getting `TypeError: checked.map is not a function`. I want the "name" key to always be the same for each object in the "checked" array, but the value for the checked property to be either true or false based on a checkbox the user clicks on. Does anyone see why I could be getting this error, and what I could do to make this work? Thanks.

```js
 const [checked, setChecked] = useState([
    { name: 'user1', checked: false },
    { name: 'user2', checked: false },
    { name: 'user3', checked: false }
  ]);

 const handleChange = (name, id) => {
    let header = id;
    let updatedList = checked.map((item) => {
      if (item.header === header) {
        return { ...item, checked: !item.checked };
      }
      return item;
    });

    setChecked(...updatedList);
}
```

Comment: where does `item.header` come from? I don't see it in the `useState`

Comment: item.header is being passed in from a Checkbox that the user clicks.

Comment: Ok, but there's no such thing as `item.header` in the state. `item` has only two attributes: `name` & `checked`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem is that you **spread** the created `updatedList` array:

```
setChecked(...updatedList);
```

Your `checked` state is an array -> you should refresh it with an array. Because you **spread** it, then the `setChecked` messes up the state & you cannot `map` it anymore (thus `.map() is not a function`).

Try `setChecked` with a function & its argument as an array:

```js
const {
  useState
} = React

const App = () => {
  const [checked, setChecked] = useState([{
      name: 'user1',
      checked: false
    },
    {
      name: 'user2',
      checked: false
    },
    {
      name: 'user3',
      checked: false
    }
  ]);

  const handleChange = ({ name, checked }) => {
    setChecked((previousChecked) => {
      return previousChecked.map(item => {
        if (item.name === name) {
          item.checked = checked
        }
        return item
      })
    })
  }

  return (
    <div> {
      checked.map(item => {
        return (
          <label>
            {
              item.name
            }
            <input type = "checkbox"
              onChange = {() => handleChange({...item, checked: !item.checked})}
            />
            <br />
          </label>
        )
      })
    }
    {
      // just so you see the change of state:
      JSON.stringify(checked)
    }
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render( <App /> , document.querySelector("#app"))
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`TypeError: checked.map is not a function` would mean "checked" is not array.

It is possible that somewhere along the way, the setChecked is called with non-array value. You should investigate, there might be an unintended setChecked happening.

In the meantime, a quick fix is to check if it's an array before calling .map

```
const handleChange = (name, id) => {
  let header = id;
  if (Array.isArray(checked)) {
    let updatedList = checked.map((item) => {
      if (item.header === header) {
        return { ...item, checked: !item.checked };
      }
      return item;
    });

    setChecked(...updatedList);
  } else {
    console.log(`checked is not array? Let's see who's behind the mask`, checked);
  }
}
```